# What is the good practice to use React.JS useEffect hook for multiple states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the best practice to use `React.JS` `useEffect` hook when listening for multiple *states change*

**first:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if ( first ) {
      // do the stuff for first state changes
    }

    if ( second ) {
      // do the stuff for second state changes
    }
  })
```

**second:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
  // do the stuff for first state changes 
  }, [first])



  useEffect(() => {
    // do the stuff for second state changes 
  }, [second])
```

and what are the **pros** and **cons** between these two methods?

Comment: The [_Motivation_ section of the hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation) touches on this, where they say the premise of hooks is to isolate complex components' stateful logic to ease reuse. So based on that motivation, separating effects would make sense. Though it's entirely opinion-based and depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the situation, but for most cases you should use separate `useEffect` for each use case.

If you do:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if ( first ) {
      // do the stuff for first state changes
    }

    if ( second ) {
      // do the stuff for second state changes
    }
  }, [first, second])
```

This `useEffect` will run every time `first` and `second` changes. You should ask yourself, do I need to check `first` and update it when `second` changes, and vice versa. If that is the case, you should combine them into a single `useEffect`, although I would personally not use separate state variables for that.

In the second case, you isolate the changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  // do the stuff for first state changes 
  }, [first])


  useEffect(() => {
    // do the stuff for second state changes 
  }, [second])
```

When `first` changes, you are going to handle the state changes for `first` and the same thing for `second`. To avoid any side effects, you should try to separate the `useEffect` calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for the 2nd option for a couple of reasons:

- Reduce unnecessary checks when combining multiple state changes
- The First option always get trigger every state/props changes
- Taking more control when to run which useEffect.
- Separate of concern

And [React actually encourage us to do that](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns).

**But it entirely depends on your case**